# Looks like we got no XML Document. Failed to read schema document

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am building up a web service but I am getting the exception "Looks like we got no XML document". I have put my wsdl file to check for XML validation but I am getting the error:

> schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document
>   'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/wsdl.xsd', because 1) could not find
>   the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element
>   of the document is not xsd:schema

I have modified xsi to xsd and even entered "XMLSchema-Instance" but nothing happened. Where is my mistake? Am I using an old version? Also I have entered a random targetNamespace, is it correct to enter any random (unexisting) namespace? Please help.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions name="Search" targetNamespace="http://www.examples.com/wsdl/Search.wsdl" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
    xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:this="http://www.examples.com/wsdl/Search.wsdl" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/ http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/ http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd">
```

Answer (score 0):

The schema reference at http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/wsdl.xsd seems to be invalid. Changing the schema location reference to http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/ should fix the error.

Comment: Could you try downloading the schema and refer it locally? Probably your IDE/editor is unable to connect to internet.